# Rust how to start thread with function

Tags: multithreading, rust

How to start this function simultaneously

I tried using thread in which I get `borrowed data escapes outside of function`

```rust
for item in 0..10{
    download_image(
        chapter_hash, // &str
        image, // &str
        name, // &str
        title, // &str
        vol, // &str
        chapter, // &str
        item, // usize
    ).await;
};
```

What I would like to do is run this function at same time.

**EDIT**

I added some comments, hope u can make head and tails from code.

It simply searches json for data and download file from these data

```rust
async fn download_chapter(
    json: String,
    name: &str,
    title: &str,
    vol: &str,
    chapter: &str,
    folder_name: &str,
) {
    match serde_json::from_str(&json) {
        Ok(json_value) => match json_value {
            Value::Object(obj) => {
                if let Some(data_array) = obj.get("chapter") {
                    // checks if chapter is in the json and store it in value
                    if let Some(chapter_hash) = data_array.get("hash").and_then(Value::as_str) {
                        // checks if hash is in chapter and store it in value
                        if let Some(images1) = data_array.get("data").and_then(Value::as_array) {
                            // same but with data
                            let images_length = images1.len(); // .and_then(Value::as_array) if just for length
                            if let Some(images) = data_array.get("data") {
                                // this json is [{...}, {...}]
                                let folder_path =
                                    format!("{} - {}Ch.{} - {}", name, vol, chapter, title);

                                // Code for creating folder

                                let pb = ProgressBar::new(images_length as u64);

                                pb.set_style(
                                        ProgressStyle::default_bar()
                                            .template("   [{elapsed_precise}] [{bar:40.cyan/blue}] {pos}/{len} ({percent}%) {msg}")
                                            .progress_chars("#>-"),
                                    );

                                for item in 0..images_length {
                                    if let Some(image) = images.get(item) {
                                        // Formatting file path
                                        let file_name = format!(
                                            "{} - {}Ch.{} - {} - {}.jpg",
                                            name,
                                            vol,
                                            chapter,
                                            title,
                                            &item + 1
                                        );
                                        let file_path = format!(
                                            "{}",
                                            file_name
                                                .replace('<', "")
                                                .replace('>', "")
                                                .replace(':', "")
                                                .replace('|', "")
                                                .replace('?', "")
                                                .replace('*', "")
                                                .replace('/', "")
                                                .replace('\\', "")
                                                .replace('"', "")
                                                .replace('\'', "")
                                        );

                                        // The function that can run in threads
                                        download_image(
                                            chapter_hash,
                                            image,
                                            name,
                                            title,
                                            vol,
                                            chapter,
                                            item,
                                        )
                                        .await;
                                        pb.inc(1);
                                    } else {
                                        println!("Image not found")
                                    }
                                }
                                pb.finish_with_message("Done downloading");
                            } else {
                                println!("Missing data for chapter")
                            }
                        } else {
                            println!("Missing data for chapter")
                        }
                    } else {
                        println!("Chapter number missing")
                    }
                } else {
                    println!("  JSON does not contain a 'chapter' array.");
                }
            }
            _ => {
                println!("  JSON is not an object.");
            }
        },
        Err(err) => println!("  Error parsing JSON: {}", err),
    }
}
```

As you guys suggested I change it, and it works just as expected

It runs max 12 threads at the time, probably because I have 12 thread processor

```rust
let tasks = (0..images_length).map(|item| {
    if let Some(image_tmp) = images.get(item) {
        let image_temp = image_tmp.to_string();

        // code for creating directory

        let chapter_hash = chapter_hash.to_string();
        let image = image_temp.trim_matches('"').to_string();
        let name = name.to_string();
        let title = title.to_string();
        let vol = vol.to_string();
        let chapter = chapter.to_string();

        tokio::spawn(async move {
            download_image(
                &chapter_hash,
                &image,
                &name,
                &title,
                &vol,
                &chapter,
                item,
            )
            .await;
        })
    } else {
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            download_image("", "", "", "", "", "", 0).await;
        })
    }
});

let _: Vec<_> =
    futures::future::join_all(tasks).await.into_iter().collect();
```

Comment: Why do you need a reference to a `usize`?

Comment: Ups, my bad in definition i had item: &usize

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pass a reference to a stack variable to a thread?](/q/32750829/2189130)

Comment: oh wait, you have a `.await` so that doesn't really help

Comment: probably just want [`futures::future::join_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/fn.join_all.html)

Comment: Use `map`, then `join_all` as kmdreko is suggesting. As for borrowing, you may need to wrap in `Arc` to make it shared.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help us help you, as well as the whole error from `cargo check` (not your IDE).

Comment: I'm quite certain your question is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You are asking for threads, and yet you are having an async function there. So what you are probably trying to ask is "How do I run multiple **tasks** asynchronously, whilst waiting for all of them to finish in the end?" Spawning threads manually is almost always wrong when dealing with async code. That's the job of the reactor, like `tokio`, and he does that internally without the user having to do anything. And yes, your answer is most likely `futures::future::join_all`, as @kmdreko already stated.

Comment: But how to do that exactly, or if any borrow checker problems still exist, is impossible to say from the minimal amount of code you provide. I agree with @ChayimFriedman, please provide a [mre].

Comment: The important question here is: Are the `&str`s `&'static str`s or `&'a str`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `async` functions, don't use threads. They are the wrong tool; the async reactor (like `tokio`) already spawns threads for you.

You just have to tell the reactor that you want to execute multiple tasks asynchronously, like with [`futures::future::join_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/fn.join_all.html).

Here is an example that is loosely based on your code:

```rust
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

async fn do_one(name: &str, item: usize, i: usize) {
    println!(
        "{:?}: Do: {}: {}, {}",
        thread::current().id(),
        i,
        name,
        item
    );
    tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100)).await;
    println!("{:?}: {} done.", thread::current().id(), i);
}

async fn do_many(name: &str, item: usize) {
    futures::future::join_all((0..10).map(move |i| do_one(name, item, i))).await;
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    do_many("foo", 42).await;
}
```

```
ThreadId(1): Do: 0: foo, 42
ThreadId(1): Do: 1: foo, 42
ThreadId(1): Do: 2: foo, 42
ThreadId(1): Do: 3: foo, 42
ThreadId(1): Do: 4: foo, 42
ThreadId(1): Do: 5: foo, 42
ThreadId(1): Do: 6: foo, 42
ThreadId(1): Do: 7: foo, 42
ThreadId(1): Do: 8: foo, 42
ThreadId(1): Do: 9: foo, 42
ThreadId(1): 0 done.
ThreadId(1): 1 done.
ThreadId(1): 2 done.
ThreadId(1): 3 done.
ThreadId(1): 4 done.
ThreadId(1): 5 done.
ThreadId(1): 6 done.
ThreadId(1): 7 done.
ThreadId(1): 8 done.
ThreadId(1): 9 done.
```

---

Additional remark:

`futures::future::join_all` does **not** cause parallelism (as can be seen by the printed thread id). So far, it's single-threaded asynchronism.
To allow tokio to schedule the tasks onto multiple threads, you need to [`tokio::spawn`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn.html) them first.

This, however, is not possible with arguments that have non-`'static` lifetimes attached to them, like your `&str`s (I assume that they are not `&'static`).

You could solve this by copying the `&str`s to owned `String`s:

```rust
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

async fn do_one(name: String, item: usize, i: usize) {
    println!(
        "{:?}: Do: {}: {}, {}",
        thread::current().id(),
        i,
        name,
        item
    );
    tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100)).await;
    println!("{:?}: {} done.", thread::current().id(), i);
}

async fn do_many(name: &str, item: usize) {
    let futures = (0..10).map(|i| {
        let name = name.to_string();
        tokio::spawn(do_one(name, item, i))
    });

    futures::future::join_all(futures).await;
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    do_many("foo", 42).await;
}
```

```
ThreadId(2): Do: 0: foo, 42
ThreadId(4): Do: 1: foo, 42
ThreadId(4): Do: 2: foo, 42
ThreadId(4): Do: 3: foo, 42
ThreadId(3): Do: 5: foo, 42
ThreadId(2): Do: 7: foo, 42
ThreadId(3): Do: 6: foo, 42
ThreadId(3): Do: 8: foo, 42
ThreadId(2): Do: 9: foo, 42
ThreadId(4): Do: 4: foo, 42
ThreadId(3): 4 done.
ThreadId(5): 5 done.
ThreadId(5): 0 done.
ThreadId(3): 6 done.
ThreadId(5): 1 done.
ThreadId(5): 2 done.
ThreadId(5): 8 done.
ThreadId(4): 9 done.
ThreadId(3): 7 done.
ThreadId(2): 3 done.
```

Note that the thread ids now indicate that this actually runs on multiple threads. Also note that some tasks run on the same thread - `tokio::spawn` does **not** cause the spawning of an OS thread. Rather, all tasks spawned by `tokio::spawn` get distributed onto the number of existing OS threads. (which most likely corresponds somehow to the number of cores the system has)

For more information, read `tokio`s [tutorial chapter about spawning](https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial/spawning).